# Bulk insert and update in mysql

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to make some bulk insert in my table but it should cater for duplicate values. If there are duplicate then it should update the rows instead of updating it.

My table is: user(id, name, url) where id is PK

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `url`) 
    VALUES 
    ('7656', 'Tom', 'http://user.com/7656'),
    ('1234', 'Jean', 'http://user.com/1234'), 
    ('8596', 'Pierre', 'http://user.com/8596'),         
    ('2035', 'Somon', 'http://user.com/2035'), 
    ('3685', 'Lola', 'http://user.com/3685')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name), url=VALUES(url)
```

Assume that all the 5 record that i am trying to insert already exist in my table with just the url to update, how should i do it?

Is it possible to update rows with bulk insert like this?

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (a, b, c) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?), 
VALUES (?, ?, ?), 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES (b), c = VALUES(c)
```

you need to set the VALUES everytime.

Also the way you've build the query is also OK but you have a ' , ' extra in the first value ('7656', 'Tom', 'http://user.com/7656' , ),

Comment: Its working, but for some reason i am updating 5 records with only 1 colum which is being changed and it tells me 10 row(s) affected. Any idea?

Comment: Can you edit your question above with the new query. I need to see how its build now

Comment: It's almost the same, i just replaced AND by , on the update part.
see above

Comment: You have a ' , ' extra in the first value ('7656', 'Tom', 'http://user.com/7656' , ),

Comment: yeah, this is a typing mistake, should be removed from there.. but this is not the thing whichh is making 10 rows affected

Comment: Its because you update on duplicate key. So you got 5 records but you update 2 values ( name and url ) so 5 names will be updated and 5 url records.

Comment: With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.